# How to change file share location on Tableau Server after publishing the workbook?

Tags: file, server, connection, share, tableau-api

I have 2 isolated environments, a **DEVELOPMENT** environment and a **PRODUCTION** environment.  I have a Tableau Workbook that references a CSV file in the Development environment on "\\*DevServer*\DataFile.csv".  When I publish to the Production environment I want to change the reference of *DevServer* to a another server in the Production Environment in order to get the proper real data file in Production Servers.  Is this possible and how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Thus far my only Solution is to have 2 different HOST files for the Development Environment and the Production Environment where by the SERVER name points to different IP Addresses for the 2 different Environments.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant solution but one that will get you past your current problem would be to add the PROD file as another datasource and then do a Replace Data Source where you are basically repointing your DEV version to your PROD version.

Caveat: make sure all your fieldnames are identical or you get to spend time fixing pink pills and broken calculations.